# Modify PHP code to get reverse order of sql output?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Is it possible to modify this code to return the categories in reverse order (i.e Highest ID first?) It's currently displaying the output with the lowest ID first. Many thanks in advance!

```
    $imageCols = JRequest::getVar("imageCols");
    $thumbWidth = JRequest::getVar("categoryThumbWidth", 4);
    $columnWidth = floor(100 / $imageCols);
    $document =JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addStyleSheet('components/com_groovygallery/css/groovygallery.css');
    $document->addScript( JURI::base().'components/com_groovygallery/js/modernizr.custom.84782.js' );
    $document->addScript( JURI::base().'components/com_groovygallery/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' );

    <?php if($this->params->get('show_page_heading')){?><h2><?php echo $this->params->get('page_heading');?></h2><?php } ?>
    <div id="groovyGalleryCats" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".groovyGalleryCat" }'>
    <?php
    foreach($this->categories as $key=>$category){
        $params = json_decode($category->params);
        $catImage = JURI::base().$params->image;
?>
<a class="groovyGalleryCat" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_groovygallery&amp;view=images&amp;filter_category='.$category->id); ?>" >
    <?php if($params->image){ ?><img src="<?php echo JURI::base().'components/com_groovygallery/timthumb.php?src='. $catImage . '&amp;zc=2&amp;w='.$thumbWidth;?>" alt="<?php echo $category->title;?>" /> <?php } ?>
    <?php echo $category->title;?>
    <?php //echo $category->description;?>
</a>

<?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <style>
a.groovyGalleryCat {width:<?php echo $columnWidth;?>%;}
    </style>

    <script src="<?php echo JURI::base().'components/com_groovygallery/js/init-cat.js'; ?>" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: Just sort $this->categories before passing to view or even better wherever you are pulling those from database.

Or if they are always in reversed order you can just use array_reverse on it.

Comment: I think yours is a paid component. Not possible to help you when the code is not with us. You have not provided any database code. If you can share that code i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the array like this (supposing that the id property is public...):

```
uasort($this->categories, function($a, $b) {
  return $a->id > $b->id ? -1 : 1;
});
```